# Deterministic Model and Stochastic Model

Tags: self-study, modeling, interpretation, stochastic-processes, randomness

Deterministic model involves no randomness, where as stochastic model involves randomness.

An example of deterministic model is: *return of $5$years of investment with an annual interest of $7$%* .

An example of stochastic model is a *regression model*.

- When do deterministic models provide a useful approximation to truly stochastic processes ?

Comment: Keeping in mind the guidelines at the self-study [tag wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info), what's your thinking on this?

Comment: @Glen_b I really don't understand that an deterministic model can be representative(approximately) of stochastic model. But it can be happened if the random variations  differ so little within subjects. But what can be example of the situation ?